# Does $=$ stand for $\iff$ in some way?

Tags: complex-analysis, logic, first-order-logic

$\iff$ is a logical connective which can only be applied to pairs of propositions. So I understand that saying $8 \iff 5+3$ doesn't make much sense, because $8$ and $5+3$ are not propositions. However, when we get to less trivial statements the border between $=$ and $\iff$ becomes more fuzzy for me. Consider the following example:

---

> Let $T_v$ be a translation of the complex plane by $v$. Let $R_a^{\phi}$ be a rotation of the plane by $\phi$ around $a$.
>
> In my Complex Analysis book, we proved $R_a^{\phi}(z) = T_k \circ R_0^{\phi}(z)$, where $k = a(1-e^{i \phi})$. That is, any rotation of $z$ around $a$ can be written as a rotation around the origin and the a suitable translation.

To me it seems that in this case, equality can definitely be interpreted as $\iff$. I can say the above statement as: (If I rotate $z$ around $a$, then I get the same result as rotating $z$ around the origin and translating) $\wedge$ (If I rotate $z$ around the origin and do a translation, then I get the same result as  rotating $z$ around $a$).

So what exactly is the relationship between $=$ and $\iff$?

Comment: But does not $R^{\phi}_a$ denote a set (as well as the right hand side $T_k\circ R^{\phi}_0$)? So to literally say that $A\Rightarrow B$ for two sets $A,B$ seems weird to me. Of course I would interpret this as $x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B$, but still, then it is not the same explicitly. I might misunderstand you, but I don't see how there is any ambiguity in the distinction here. The difference is the one you described yourself.

Comment: I still fail to see how your example isn't also a situation where we have objects instead of propositions.

Comment: @Christopher.L That's right, I should've thought of $R^{\phi}_a$ as a set. The sentence in which I "converted" = to $\iff$ is probably translated to ($x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B) \wedge (x\in B \Rightarrow x\in A)$.

Comment: In a nutshell, the relationship between $=$ and $⟺$ is : the first is a relations between "objects", the second between sentences.

Comment: @TheCount I thought I "converted" = to $\iff$ below, the yellow block, but I believed I now have the correct interpretation, as written in my comment to Cristopher L.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'll elaborate on my comment and make it in to a answer instead*:

I would say that the distinction between '$=$' and '$\Leftrightarrow$' that you made yourself, still holds in your example. The symbol '$=$' denotes a relation between objects while '$\Leftrightarrow$' is a logical connective relating statements that are true or false.

Remember that a function is a subset of a cartesian product of the domain and codomain, so in your example, $R^{\phi}_a$ and $T_k\circ R^{\phi}_0$ both denote sets, and therefore $R^{\phi}_a=T_k\circ R^{\phi}_0$. Writing $A\Rightarrow B$ for two sets $A,B$, would be literally wrong, but could of course be interpreted as $x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B$.

Comment: But what would be an example of an element of the set $R^{\phi}_a$? If we take every point in $\mathbb{C}$ and rotate it by $\phi$ around $a$, won't the result look just like the original set $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: In general, an element of a function $f:A\to B$ looks like $(a,b)$ for some $a\in A, b\in B$, i.e $f\subset A\times B$. The function $f$ relates all elements of $A$ with an element of $B$, so $(x,f(x))$ is more appropriate. An element of $R^{\phi}_a$ then looks like $(z,f(z))\in \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$. So, $R^{\phi}_a\subset \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$. However, the function will take on values in $\mathbb{C}$, that is called the range, and that will be the whole of $\mathbb{C}$. However, $f$ will not be the whole of $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$ since for example $(0,a)\not\in f$.

Comment: So to shortly answer your question in the comments: You are probably referring to the function as the range, i.e. $\{y\in \mathbb{C}|y=f(x)\}$, this will be $\mathbb{C}$. The function in itself is often also interpreted as a set as described above. Either way, when writing $f$ for a function, we are dealing with sets that are objects and not statements. Otherwise you would have to write $y=f(x)\Rightarrow y=g(x)$ or such.

Answer (score 2):

Equality can't be interpreted as a biconditional in your example. "The rotation map… is equal to the translation composed with the other rotation map." Under your interpretation using "iff" instead of "=", the expression would read "A rotation map if and only if a rotation followed by a translation", which is just grammatically wrong.